# Home Assistant: Command_line & REST Switch

Tags: api, rest, yaml, home-assistant

I am trying to unlock my door through HA, it's a straightforward HTTPS link but in the last variable of the link "date=" we need to assign the current date, which I think is the one that is causing issues with my below code:

```
switch:
  - platform: command_line
    switches:
      home_door_four:
        command_on: "curl -k  https://api.ttlock.com/v3/lock/unlock?clientId=xxxxx&accessToken=xxxxx&lockId=xxxxx&date={{ (now().timestamp() | int * 1000 ) }}"
        command_off: "curl -k  https://api.ttlock.com/v3/lock/lock?clientId=xxxxx&accessToken=xxxxx&lockId=xxxxx&date={{ (now().timestamp() | int * 1000 ) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using the ***rest_command*** and ***template lock*** integration.

*NB: This is just a snippet of my code, I'm sure you can fill in the blanks, I also use a door sensor and also get the lock status from the API.*

```yaml
rest_command:
  unlock:
    method: POST
    content_type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    url: >
      https://api.ttlock.com/v3/lock/unlock?clientId=xxxxxxx&accessToken=xxxxxxx&lockId=xxxxxxx&date={{ as_timestamp(now()) | int * 1000 }}
```

Then create the lock:

```yaml
lock:
  - platform: template
    name: myLock
    optimistic: true
    lock:
      service: rest_command.lock
    unlock:
      service: rest_command.unlock
```